# Signing out of Sitecore with Azure AD

Tags: azure, identity-server, azure-ad

We are working on an upgrade from `Sitecore 8.2` to `10.2` with an `Azure AD` sign-in/sign-out component. Right now, when a user is logged in with Azure AD in Sitecore and clicks the logout button it is logging them out of all of the Azure AD accounts. Is there a way to prevent this and only log them out of Sitecore?

I can't find any exact documentation describing how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config` file. You can find this file on the following location: `\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\`.

Search for the following setting:

```
<triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
```

If you change that to `false` it should only log you out of Sitecore and not Azure AD.